# Meu navigation drawer não vai mais para as minhas telas, apenas um botão de logout que eu fiz, as demais não chamam a outra tela

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;


    ImageView imageView_Carrinho;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imageView_Carrinho = findViewById(R.id.imageView_Carrinho);


        imageView_Carrinho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarrinhoAdapter.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

       // Cria referencia para toda a area do navigation drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        //Cria referencia para a area de navegação
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        NavigationView navigationView1 = findViewById(R.id.nav_sair);


        //Define configurações do navigation drawer
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        //Configura area que ira carregar os fragments
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        //Configura menu superior da navegação
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);

        //Configura
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                        {
                            case R.id.nav_sair:
                                //faça qualquer ação aqui
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                finish();
                                startActivity(intent);

                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }**/

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    

}
```

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            android:background="@drawable/degrade_menu2"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/Branco"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/Branco"
           />
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>```
````

Comment: Diga a que parte do app cada código se refere. No título informe apenas o problema, deixe para dar os detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: perdão, sou novo rs

Answer (score 0):

Eai parceiro, joia? Espero poder lhe ajudar!
Geralmente, quando usamos o recurso do drawer layout, temos um arquivo xml, chamado mobile navigation ou o nome dado por você, que é possível definir os fragments que temos e suas indicações de navegação (como o próprio nome diz), isso possibilita você conseguir clicar nos itens do navigation drawer e ir à outros fragments.
Com a minha experiência, que não é muito grande, presumo que, com o drawer layout, é mais facil a movimentação entre fragments, porém se for uma interação fragment -> activity, procure inserir em seu código o recurso onNavigationItemSelected() na sua classe principal, assim, presume-se resolver seu erro!
Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

"Você falou deixar que eu assumo a navegação e o android diz: ok, a responsabilidade é toda sua!"

Quando voce colocou o:

```
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.nav_sair:
                            //faça qualquer ação aqui
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);

                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Você está assumindo a navegação. Desse modo, você deve atribuir as telas em seus respectivos ID do menu, segue exemplo:

```
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMainDrawer.toolbarCustom.toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

    //Define configurações do navigation drawer
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_resumo_pedido,
            R.id.nav_evento,
            R.id.nav_relatorio_vendas)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    //Configura area que ira carregar os fragments
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main_drawer);
    //Configura menu superior da navegação
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    //Configura
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home: //ID DO MENU
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home); //navegando
                    drawer.close(); // fechar o drawer
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_resumo_pedido:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_resumo_pedido);
                    drawer.close();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_evento:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_evento);
                    drawer.close();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_relatorio_vendas:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_relatorio_vendas);
                    drawer.close();
                    break;

            }
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Assim você consegue navegar entre as telas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).